# Sql multiple columns orders

Tags: mysql, sql

Not really sure how to explain this on the title so it might be wrong.
SQL is not my main strength so sorry in advance if this is a stupid question :)
Using MySql by the way.

I have this query:

```
SELECT
ru.user_id AS "User Id",
ru.first_name AS "First Name"
FROM member_referral_users AS ru
ORDER BY ru.user_id DESC, ru.first_name ASC
```

the result set looks like this:

[image: result set]

I want the order to be Admin,angelo,emma,emma,carlos,chris,emma

I guess the order should be name first but I want those users (guests really) to be on the bottom since they have 0 as user_id

All the help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ru.user_id AS "User Id",
  ru.first_name AS "First Name"
FROM member_referral_users AS ru
ORDER BY 
  ru.user_id = 0,
  ru.first_name ASC
```

`ru.user_id = 0` will be evaluated either to TRUE (=1) or to FALSE (=0) and ordering by `ru.user_id = 0` will put records with user_id=0 at the bottom.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc4d/1).

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, all the other answers didnt take in consideration the User Id = 0

In 8 minutes I will officially accept your answer, you are a star :D

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ru.user_id    AS "User Id",
  ru.first_name AS "First Name"
FROM member_referral_users AS ru
ORDER BY ru.first_name ASC , ru.user_id ASC
```

Comment: In this way emma can never preceed carlos and chris, as Angelo wants to.